# CakePHP find with MAX and group by

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a table with multiple records for users, such as their login dates and IP addresses.

So, I want to get last IP address or last login date for every user in my database, for last `n` days.

When I try to use `"group"` in cakephp find, it does not show the correct records:

```
$data = $this->Login->find('all',
    array(
          'conditions'=>array('Login.last_login_date<='=>$d),
          'group'=>'Login.user_id',
          'order'=>array('Login.last_login_date'=>'DESC'),
          'fields' => array('MAX(Login.last_login_date) AS last_login_date', '*','User.*')
    )
);
```

What might be the cause of this?

Comment: remember tha when you group you can't be sure of what mysql shows for columns that are not aggregated. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track by ordering by the login date desc.  You actually don't need to find the `MAX` of the login date here though.  If you want to get the last login date, just order by the login date descending. Whatever the login date value is after grouping will be the last login date.

```
$data = $this->Login->find('all', array(
    // Assuming that the login date column is login_date here
    'conditions' => array('Login.login_date <=' => $d), 
    'group' => 'Login.user_id',
    'order' => array('Login.login_date' => 'DESC'), 
    'fields' => array('*', 'User.*')
));
```